# php parse and merge arrays returns wrong data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a array that contains user ids and i want to get each user's data and put all user ids and datas in different arrays like this :

```
array 1 : ['user 1' => ['user data'] ]
array 2 : ['user 2' => ['user data'] ]
```

I already wrote this code but gives me wrong data

```
    foreach ($users->userids as $user){
        $commentusers=[];
        $nodeusers=[];
        $postQuery = InstaPost::select('post.id','userid')->where('userid',$user)->get();
        if (count($postQuery) > 0 ){
            foreach ($postQuery as $item){
                $postArr[] = $item->post['id'];
            }
            foreach ($postArr as $key => $value){

                $commentquery = comment::select('comment.owner.id','comment.owner.username','postid')->where('postid',$value)->get()->unique('comment.owner.id')->toArray();
                if (count($commentquery) > 0){
                    foreach ($commentquery as $eachpost){
                        $commentusers[] = $eachpost['comment']['owner']['username'];
                    }
                }
                $thread_comment = DB::table('Comments')->select('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges.node.owner.username','comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges.node.owner.id','postid')->where('postid','=',$value)->where('comment.edge_threaded_comments.count','>',0 )->get()->unique('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges.node.owner.id')->toArray();
                foreach ($thread_comment as $eachthread){
                    $edges = $eachthread['comment']['edge_threaded_comments']['edges'];
                    foreach ($edges as $edge){
                        $nodeusers[] = $edge['node']['owner']['username'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $result = array_merge($nodeusers,$commentusers);
        $result = array_values(array_unique($result));
        $merge[$user] = $result;
    }
```

as you can see in picture first array is a correct result but second array duplicates first array with it's own data

[image]

this is a result when i'm just getting 1 user's data and everything is correct.
[image]

Comment: You are only posting a subset of the second array, so I can't say for certain, but the last three items in the first array don't appear in the second array. Additionally, since we don't have your database, you are probably going to have to debug this on your own. Just put a bunch of dumps at key locations to see if what you expect matches what you have. You have a `for` loop nested 4 deep there's a lot of room for surprises.

Comment: as you can see in the second array i have 1156 items, not in the picture but they are all in the second one, i think problem is with the last 3 variables (merge, unique and put it all through one array). I added a picture of getting just one user's data, it gives me correct information ! but when it comes to 2 or more user ids, everything's a mess and duplicate

Comment: I am not going to read through all that code, but I would bet you can do what you need to do by eager loading some properly configured relationships.

Comment: my database is MongoDB and i want to fetch system user's data. basically I have userids and i need to get each user's postid and after that get comments and nested comments, i don't know how to do it with eager loading.